# How to use \eqalignno properly?

Tags: vertical-alignment, subequations

I'm trying to use the following aligned equations, but It does not work and gives bunch of error. This is my first time trying to use this command so kind of struggling to make it right. I could find what is wrong with it.

```
\eqalignno{\min_{V} \quad & V^{H}C_{0}V & \hbox{(6a)} \cr
         {\rm s.t}.\quad &\underline{p}_{j}\leq V^{H}\Phi_{j}^{\phi}V\leq\bar{p}_{j},\quad j\in N, \phi \in\Phi&\hbox{(6b)}\cr
         & \underline{q}_{j}\leq V^{H}\Psi_{j}^{\phi}V\leq\bar{q}_{j},\quad j\in N,\phi\in\Phi&\hbox{(6c)}\cr
         & \underline{v}_{j}\leq V^{H}E_{j}^{\phi}V\leq\bar{v}_{j},\quad j\in N, \phi\in\Phi&\hbox{(6d)}}
```

Comment: Works for me. Did you forget to enclose these equations in `$$` `$$`? Do you really use PlainTeX?

Comment: I get a bunch of error if this is used in a LaTeX document.

Comment: I enclosed it by $$, and get bunch of error like @egreg said. Do I need any special package to be able to use this? I'm using it in the following file '\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}'

Comment: @Fred `\eqalignno` is not defined in LaTeX. You want to look at the documentation for `amsmath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what this command  achieves can be obtained by `align` nested in a `subequations` environment. Maybe you'd be interested in grouping the three constraints as a single subequation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{5}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    \min_{V} \quad & V^{H}C_{0}V \\
  \textrm{s.t. } \quad &\underline{p}_{j}\leq V^{H}\Phi_{j}^{\phi}V\leq\bar{p}_{j},\quad j\in N, \phi \in\Phi \\
         & \underline{q}_{j}\leq V^{H}\Psi_{j}^{\phi}V\leq\bar{q}_{j},\quad j\in N,\phi\in\Phi \\
         & \underline{v}_{j}\leq V^{H}E_{j}^{\phi}V\leq\bar{v}_{j},\quad j\in N, \phi\in\Phi
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
   & \min_{V } \quad V^{H}C_{0}V \\
 & \begin{rcases}
  \textrm{s.t. } &\underline{p}_{j}\leq V^{H}\Phi_{j}^{\phi}V\leq\bar{p}_{j},\quad j\in N, \phi \in\Phi \\
         & \underline{q}_{j}\leq V^{H}\Psi_{j}^{\phi}V\leq\bar{q}_{j},\quad j\in N,\phi\in\Phi \\
         & \underline{v}_{j}\leq V^{H}E_{j}^{\phi}V\leq\bar{v}_{j},\quad j\in N, \phi\in\Phi
\end{rcases}
  \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

 \end{document}
```

[image]